# DDE Link with different data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a DDE service which returns some value for each different data (last parameter). I want to send to this service different values for each cell:

```
=MyService|SERVERTIME!'anything'
```

So when I copy these cells I want something like this:

```
=MyService|SERVERTIME!'1'
=MyService|SERVERTIME!'2'
=MyService|SERVERTIME!'3'
=MyService|SERVERTIME!'4'
```

The problem is when I try to do something like this:
`=MyService|SERVERTIME!ROW()` Excel thinks the part `"=MyService|SERVERTIME!ROW"` is the DDE link function and it has no idea what to do with `"()"`. So I cannot use any functions after the exclamation mark.

Please let me know, if the question is not clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating it? Like: `=INDIRECT("MyService|SERVERTIME!"&ROW())`. Not sure though if `INDIRECT` works with DDE.

Comment: I got interested and after some fishing in the net found [THIS](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/344076-concatenating-dde-link.html#post1697756). So `INDIRECT` is not an option. I think the routine is pretty simple, so you can adapt to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did something like that yesterday. But apparently there is no real solution.